# Mixing existing website with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

If I want to use Jinja templating with GAE, is there a way to do that from my hosted website?  I don't want to run the entire website on appspot.com.

If my host has python installed, I should be able to install Jinja there as well?  In that case, I'm guessing my templating code will still work but anything in the app.yaml and main.py will not since I'll basically not be using GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use Jinja on any python web framework -- [here's](http://pycourse.com/posts/2013/Jul/16/Templating%20and%20Jinja2/) just one example I found of a tutorial using Jinja without app engine. Jinja is just an HTML templating library that's host/web platform independent.

Comment: Would the code just before he starts going into Flask go into a main.py?  Can any handlers also go there (for multiple or child pages)?